# AngularJS run a series of functions on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I need to run a series of functions on the loading of a state that will prepare the page for the user.

These functions are basically three calls to Parse.com (cannot combine them into one query as they are in different classes)

The three functions (parse.com queries) are:

1. Get users favourites
2. Get page data
3. Get users saved data

Whilst I have these three functions separately I would like a more robust method of doing this rather than running the functions one after another like this:

```
getFavourites();
getPageData();
getUserData();
```

My three functions are like so:

```
var getFavourites = function() {
    var query = {
        user: {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": Parse.User.current().id
        }
    };

    ParseFactory.provider('Favourites', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
        var favouritesArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            favouritesArray = data.results[i].favourites;
        };

        $localStorage.favourites = favouritesArray;

        favouriteExerciseIds();

        // elasticFavouriteSearch(favouriteIds);

    }).error(function(response) {
        errorFactory.checkError(response);
    });
};


var getSavedExercises = function() {
    var query = {
        'userId': Parse.User.current().id
    };
    ParseFactory.provider('UserExercises', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
        var savedExercises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var exercise = {
                exerciseName: data.results[i].exerciseName,
                exerciseDescription: data.results[i].exerciseDescription,
                images: data.results[i].images,
                difficulty: data.results[i].difficulty,
                id: data.results[i].objectId
            }
            savedExercises.push(exercise);
        };
        $localStorage.savedExercises = savedExercises;

    }).error(function(response) {
        errorFactory.checkError(response);
    });
};



var getPageData = function() {
    ParseFactory.provider('Programme/').get($stateParams.loadProgramme).success(function(data) {
            $localStorage.programme = data;
            $scope.programme = $localStorage.programme;
            addedExercises();
        }).error(function(response) {
            errorFactory.checkError(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more robust" way? What is not robust about calling them this way? (if they are always called together, you can make a 4th function that calls these, so at your initial call, you only have to call that one fn instead of three)

Comment: You could add them to the app run block in your angular is code, also you could wrap them in promises and have them call one after the other in the then() handlers in each http request made so you can be sure they have all returned some data.

Comment: By more robust way I mean that if one fails or gives an error then the rest are dependent on the the one previously, no? Would promises help - I don't fully understand how they would work?

Comment: @mindparse how can I make them into a chain of promises?

Comment: Take a look at the $http service angular provides you will find plenty of examples out there how to using this will return a promise which you can use for chaining multiple requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all of your method return a promise and 
then You can use `$q.all` method to show the page after all the promises has been resolved.

Check the below code,

```
var init = function(){

    $q.all([ getFavourites(), getSavedExercises(), getPageData() ]).then(function(responses){
        //Show The page, check responses for promise success 

    });

};

var getFavourites = function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var query = {
        user: {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": Parse.User.current().id
        }
    };

    ParseFactory.provider('Favourites', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
        var favouritesArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            favouritesArray = data.results[i].favourites;
        };

        $localStorage.favourites = favouritesArray;

        favouriteExerciseIds();

        // elasticFavouriteSearch(favouriteIds);
        deferred.resolve('');

    }).error(function(response) {
        errorFactory.checkError(response);
        deferred.reject(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};


var getSavedExercises = function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var query = {
        'userId': Parse.User.current().id
    };
    ParseFactory.provider('UserExercises', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
        var savedExercises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var exercise = {
                exerciseName: data.results[i].exerciseName,
                exerciseDescription: data.results[i].exerciseDescription,
                images: data.results[i].images,
                difficulty: data.results[i].difficulty,
                id: data.results[i].objectId
            }
            savedExercises.push(exercise);
        };
        $localStorage.savedExercises = savedExercises;

        deferred.resolve('');


    }).error(function(response) {
        errorFactory.checkError(response);

        deferred.reject(response);

    });

    return deferred.promise;

};



var getPageData = function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();


    ParseFactory.provider('Programme/').get($stateParams.loadProgramme).success(function(data) {
        $localStorage.programme = data;
        $scope.programme = $localStorage.programme;
        addedExercises();

        deferred.resolve('');

    }).error(function(response) {
        errorFactory.checkError(response);
        deferred.reject(response);

    });

    return deferred.promise;

}
```